# Correct way to fit a line in 3D (x-position vs y-position vs other quantity)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, total-least-squares

I have measured the position of light spots $(x,y)$ in an arbitrarily chosen basis and I compare that to some other measured quantity, say the brightness of each spot $B$.

Now, in theory all the spots should lay on a line $y=ax+b$. Let's call the distance along the line $d$. Than $d$ as a function of $B$ should be an affine function $d = cB + d_0$.

**How do I find the best approximation of $c$?**

​

If $(x,y,B)$ were an actual physical space, the correct way would be to do an [Orthogonal Distance Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) of a line right away. But since $B$ is a different quantity, the result would heavily depend on the choice of $B$'s units, wouldn't it?

The second thing that came across my mind would be to do an [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) to find the line in $(x,y)$, then project all points on that line and do [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) on $(B,d)$.

Another possible solution would be to do two [Linear Regressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) on $(B,x)$ and $(B,y)$ and use the fact that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal to reconstruct the line in $(x,y,B)$.

But I don't know which one is best, whether some of those are equivalent, or if any of them is correct.

Comment: The units affect the magnitude of the fitted parameters only. For example, if nuclear weapon yield is measured in kilotons or micrograms the underlying physical relationship being modeled is the same.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Not in ODR afaik.

Comment: How exactly is the "position $d$" defined? Specifically, if I knew $a,$ $b,$ and $d,$ how would I locate the point it references?

Comment: @whuber I changed the equation for $x,y$. I thought I'd write a generic line equation and didn't really think about it. With this new correct equation, $d=y \sqrt{1+a^2}$ plus an arbitrary additive constant.

Comment: sounds like your model is obtained by rotating a position the 1-d line, to form a 2-D space (x,y). As this is a linear combination of (B,x,y), fitting a linear model B on both (x,y), then rotate the fitted parameters. where is the error/noise though?

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused now, because your question variously refers to "all the spots" and to "that spot" and it posits that a key quantity, $d,$ is not even well-defined (it includes an "arbitrary additive constant")!  The problem with the units of measurement of $B$ appears to be non-existent, because it merely affects the units in which $c$ must be expressed.  Could you perhaps illustrate your setup or describe the problem a little more concretely?

Comment: @whuber The spots should lay on a line, $d$ is distance along the line, but since I haven't measured it directly, I need to extrapolate that from $x,y$. And "that spot" is just a sloppy way to say "each spot". Sorry for that. I'll try to improve the question with more concrete description in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is PCA. Apply it to your three dimensional data, and if you're right, then first principal component PC1 should explain almost all variance. The coefficients of PC1 will give you what you're looking for.

PCA looks for linear combinations $w_1 x+w_2y+w_3B$ that explain as much variance in the data set as possible. If all your points are laying on one line, then there'd be only one eigen value (or principal component) that captures all the variance of your data. So, get the PC1 and its coefficients $w_i$ will tell you the line.